# JQuery ScrollTop not working with Overflow

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

When building my mobile website, I had to add these properties to my body to eliminate excess whitespace:

```
html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

However, my jQuery `scrollTop` functions, regarding parallax and the navbar, do not work now. These functions do not work on mobile.

```
$n = ".navbar";
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 300){
        $($n).css("background-color", "rgba(255,255,255,.2)");
    } else {
        $($n).css("background-color", "transparent");
    }
});
```

I have tried removing the overflow from the body, and keeping it solely on HTML, and vice versa, which does fix my issue, however the whitespace returns. I have looked online, however I cannot seem to find anything regarding this issue.

If you want to view the website, the URL is http://studysesh.us.
Keep in mind, it is just beginning, currently the homepage is the only page.
Thank you.

Comment: mhm.... When I shrink my window to a mobile resolution, there is nothing more displaying in the console. I'm gonna assume that this `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` is the cause. (testing in vivaldi with google dev tools)

Comment: Yes. I added a media query to remove the overflow unless the window is roughly mobile size. I am not sure why it does not pick up the scrolling. What I do notice is that the scrolling does log when you bounce the browser (meaning either at top or bottom)

Comment: An other thing strange. If you scroll down then shrink the window to mobile resolution, it's ok. If you now stretch it a little bit, the window will come back to top. If you shrink it again, it will go back to the last position. It's like something is reseted or like you have two different document... weird

Comment: @TCHdvlp What element are you talking about? I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: I just scrolled down then played with the window dimensions. I talk about the whole window.

Comment: @TCHdvlp Oh, I see what you mean. I am not sure what is causing that, possibly the middle div collapsing.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out by removing the `height` property on the `body`, which literally is equivalent to setting the `height` to `auto`.

```
body {
   height: auto;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

> When you set a value to the `height` of the `body` explicitly, scrolling on any area over it would actually trigger `scroll` event inside the `body` itself, and not the `window`. In my opinion, this was the source of the problem with the `scroll` event not being fired.

Meanwhile, `overflow-y: scroll;` is redundant and needless in your case, as it forces an ugly scroll-bar on the `body` when the width of the viewport is reduced significantly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be caused by the

```
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Try to change them by

```
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: Nope, tried it out. The scroll still does not work, nothing logs in console.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue where `scrollTop()` was not working. Turns out it was because I had some inline styles at the top of the page. It seems `scrollTop()` expects a certain HTML structure so having the `<style>` tag as the first element on the page breaks it. This is what it looked like before the fix:

```
<style>
    .my-class {
        ...
    }
</style>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
</html>
```

I moved the inline stylse into the `<head>` tag which resolved the issue. Here's how it looks after the fix:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
            .my-class {
                ...
            }
        </style>
    </head>
</html>
```